# How do I add color to ShaderMaterial in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

I'm pretty new to three.js, so try to bear with me here. So, I was assigned a project that involves creating a car body with WebGL and denting it on mousedown. I'm trying to change the color of the dents from the color of the car body to yellow. Any idea how to do that? Note: I only want to change the color of the dents, not the entire car.

Here's the code for the material of the dents. My first thought was to add color to the shader material, but that didn't work, so I commented it out.

```
var dentMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms : {
        size : { type: 'f', value : 20.0 },
        near : { type: 'f', value : camera.near },
        far  : { type: 'f', value : camera.far }
        //color:  { type: 'v3', value: { x: 1, y: 1, z: 1 } }
       // map  : { type: "t", value : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/heatmap.jpg' ) } //here
      },
      attributes : {},
      vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
      vertexShader: vertShader,
      fragmentShader: fragShader,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      transparent: true
});
```

This code is where the dents are actually created.

```
 THREE.DentModifier = function () {};

THREE.DentModifier.prototype = {

constructor: THREE.DentModifier,

set: function ( origin, direction, radius, depth, material ) {

    this.origin = origin; // vec3
    this.direction = direction; // vec3
    this.radius = radius; // float
    this.depth = depth; // float
    //this.material = material // GLmaterial
    return this;

},  

magnitude: function(vector) {
    return vector.x * vector.x + vector.y * vector.y + vector.z * vector.z;
},

linearFalloff: function (distance, radius) {    
    return this.clamp01(1 - distance / radius);
},

gaussFalloff:function (distance, radius) {
    return this.clamp01(Math.pow(360, Math.pow(distance / radius, 2.5) - .01));
},

needleFalloff:function (distance, radius) {
    return -(distance * distance / (radius * radius) + 1);
},

clamp01: function(val) {
    if (val < 0) return 0;
    if(val > 1) return 1;
    return val;
},

modify: function ( mesh , material ) {

    this.mesh = mesh;
    var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse( this.mesh.matrixWorld );
    var origin = this.origin.applyMatrix4( matrix );

    var normal = new THREE.Vector3(); 
    normal.copy( this.direction );
    normal.multiplyScalar( -this.radius * ( 1 - this.depth ) );

    var centerSphere = new THREE.Vector3();
    centerSphere.addVectors( origin, normal );
    var sphere = new THREE.Sphere( centerSphere, this.radius );

    this.mesh.geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = false;
    var sqrRadius = 100; //this.radius*this.radius;
    var sqrMagnitude; //float
    for ( var i = 0, il = this.mesh.geometry.vertices.length; i < il; i++ ) {

        if ( centerSphere.distanceTo( this.mesh.geometry.vertices[ i ] ) < this.radius ) {

            // new - Limit depth of dent
            sqrMagnitude = this.magnitude(this.mesh.geometry.vertices[i]) - this.magnitude(centerSphere);
            if (sqrMagnitude > sqrRadius) {
                console.log("We are too deep Scotty !!");
                break;
            } // end new

            var ray = new THREE.Ray( this.mesh.geometry.vertices[ i ], this.direction );
            var dent = ray.intersectSphere( sphere );
            this.mesh.geometry.vertices[ i ] = dent;                

        }

    };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dentMaterial.uniforms.diffuse = { type: "c", value: { r:1, g:0, b:0 } };`

Or when using default **phongShader uniforms** this works:

`dentMaterial.uniforms.diffuse.value.setHex ( 0xFF0000 );`

Three.js r.71

Comment: Thanks, this works. What does the "c" stand for? I'm unable to find the docs on it

Comment: Sorry I dont know the answer to this anymore, its been too long :-(